# Why does this simple subtraction does not work?

Tags: php, codeigniter

So this will be very specific question, but I am losing my sanity as I was staring at this for the better part of the day. So here I wrote this function to calculate the price dependent commission:

```
function commision($amount, $commision_arg = 0){
// $temp_amount = 0;
// $commision = 0;

if($amount > 999){

    $temp_amount = $amount - 999;
    $commision_arg += $temp_amount/100*1;
    return commision(999, $commision_arg);

}else if($amount>249&&$amount<=999){

    $temp_amount = $amount - 249;
    $commision_arg += $temp_amount/100*3;
    return commision(249, $commision_arg);

}else if($amount>49 && $amount<=249){

    $temp_amount = $amount - 49;
    $commision_arg += $temp_amount/100*5;
    return commision(49, $commision_arg);

}else if($amount <= 49){

    return number_format($commision_arg + 3.5, 2);

}

}
```

Basically if `$amount` is less then 49 then it is just flat 3.5 rate, if `$amount` is 49 to 249 then it is flat rate 3.5 + 5% of anything in 49-249 range.

I am not sure if this is good way to do this or not, but it works. However there is issue with another method that uses this function:

```
public function amountPayable(){
    $amount = $this->uri->segment(3);
    echo $amount - commision($amount);
}
```

This is just a function in codeigniter controller, that is called by AJAX request, and it should be returning the amount payable by the customer, which is then injected into DOM.

And this is where the problem lies. 
Basically if I pass the `$amount` that equal to `100.000`, what I get back from `amountPayable` is `99.999`, whereas it should be: `98973.9`. if I change `echo $amount - commision($amount);` to `echo commision($amount);` then I get back 1026.1. So the `commision()` function returns the correct number. But for some reason `$amount - commision($amount);` (where `$amount` = 100000) evaluates to 1.

How can this be?

Comment: There is not much point in using recursion here, you can just put all `if` statements after each other.

Comment: return number_format($commision_arg + 3.5, 2); Why the 3.5 ??

Comment: @jeroen, well you need to, because if we pass 1000 all 3 branches of the iff statement need to be visited.

Comment: @JamesAnderson 3.5 is the flat rate for 0 - 49.

Comment: Yes, so you remove the `else`'s and sum all amounts.

Comment: @galdikas -- but why are you adding a rate to an amount ? Or do you meet a fixed commission. i.e. he gets $3.50 even if he only sells a dollars worth!

Comment: AI think I know how you mean. I might change that. Anyway, that is not the issue. It might be over engineered but it returns the correct amount somehow lol What doesn't work is the simple part weirdly enough lol

Comment: Unless you accidentally declare your variables global in your functions, I don't see how a simple substraction can cause your problem. But you'd better do a `va_dump()` of both amounts and post it here, perhaps there is some weird typecasting going on or you have leading zeros that make php think they are not decimal numbers.

Comment: The fault is that the 'commission' functions returns a number string which looks like _1,026.01_  - note the comma. When this is converted back to a number by PHP it stops at the comma - returning 1. The 'commission' function should return the floating point number and it should be formatted elsewhere.